# How to select from a table with two columns but one of them is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stuck at my SELECT statement. I am looking for an Item by code and definition. I have a select statement like below...

```
select * from t_items where code ='#itemcode#' OR definition like '%#definition#%'
```

the user can select the #itemcode# from a dropdown menu on the web screen, or the user enters a test into the definition textbox. Because of the "LIKE", it returns everything.

what is the good way of doing this?

Comment: How are you passing the parameters, please ? What is Hash (#) ? Do you know that your code is possibly vulnerable for SQL Injection this way ? Your site could be hijacked easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like :

```
select * 
from t_items where (code ='#itemcode#' 
and #itemcode# is not null)
OR (definition like '%#definition#%' 
and #definition# is not null)
```

Comment: In such cases, the SQLPolice **must** immediatedly intercept. What is that hash # please? How are you passing the parameters? **RED CARD** for opening up the gates for **SQL Injection**!